# Calculating Time Metrics for HTTP request in Java

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

Is there any Open Source component that can make a HTTP request and computes different metrics like Connect Time (Socket Connect), Time to First Byte Download, Total Download Time etc? I am looking at Apache HTTP Client but it doesn't look like it has API to provide these metrics. Thanks.

Comment: Not Wireshark. I need to calculate these numbers/metrics in my Java program. I have an existing application that opens a socket and does the download.. I want to replace that with an OS alternative. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Metrics](http://metrics.codahale.com/). It supports Apache HttpClient among other things.

Comment: the link is broken, any update on the link Metrics?